# Wifi connects but no internet

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I am using ubuntu 16 and i am successfully connected to the wifi but i have no intenet access. Firefox says: Server not found. And chrome is saying DNS not found or something. All other devices are connected and are having access normaly. Olny my Ubuntu Laptop has not. If i try `ping google.com` i get unknown host google.com . I have tryied every possible solution given in this site. No one seems to be working. I do not know what else to try. The thing is that when i connect with ethernet i am getting the exactly same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ping your router. If that works, try entering a dns manually. Click top right on networking icon -> Edit connections -> Wireless connection name -> click on IPv4 Settings -> (additional DNS Servers) add your router's IP or DNS in your country). Reboot pc (sometimes only restarting networking doesn't help)